# Forgot wallet encryption password, are any brute force tools available?

Tags: wallet, encryption, passphrase

I have an idea of what my password should be, but am missing something.

Are there any tools or bash scripts to brute force my wallet passwords?

If a dictionary is required, I can pre seed it as necessary (but if I pre-seed a dictionary with my expected passwords that utility better be FOSS so I can review the source ;)  )

Comment: what do you know, I figured out my password 10 seconds after posting this.  Perhaps this will be of future use to other people in the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a script provided by a forum user Revalin](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85495.msg942171#msg942171) which can be used to attempt variations.  There is a forum user Rix who may be available for [hire to provide assistance](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85495.msg965203#msg965203) with this type of problem.

You can also try out this script:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=170694.0